# Unable to track the firing trigger's source or its name for any tag in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, event-tracking

Is it possible to push the firing trigger's source or name to Data Layer as a variable for any tag?

Just for an instance, I have a tag with multiple firing triggers where only one trigger at time is fired perfectly without any issues. But to meet my needs, I should also push the trigger's source or name along with it track for Google Analytics: GA4 Event, would it be possible with any **Data layer variable or JavaScript Variable**?

[image: My Tag and the firing triggers at GTM]

*I am seeking to set this up like a variable or data that can be pushed as a parameter or data layer.*
So, it would be useful for any other such scenarios in future too.

Any possible solution in terms of code or any guidance to existing settings shall be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not so complicated

If your `Click - Footer Subscribe Link` trigger condition is `button.sub-footer`

And `Click - Header Subscribe Link` trigger condition is `button.sub-header`

Then just create a custom variable

```
function(){
  var clickElement = {{Click Element}};
  if(clickElement.match("button.sub-footer")){
    return "Footer Subscribe Link";
  }else if(clickElement.match("button.sub-header")){
    return "Header Subscribe Link";
  }
  return undefined
}
```

So your GA4 event tag can get the information from this `Variable`

You might need to change the code inside to comply to your real html code or trigger.

Comment: Thank your for that, I actually came across through this of solutions earlier but primarily, I am looking for more like a permanent solution for any such instance.